# Unrecognized data type error in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query but I keep getting Unrecognized datatype near C.id.
What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc`
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE 
  temp_table  
AS (
  SELECT UNIQUE(C.id) FROM table1AS C
                INNER JOIN table2 AS CA ON CA.college_id in (8192)
                INNER JOIN table3 AS CS ON CS.skill_id in (2744)
)

select * from temp_table

END
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc`()
BEGIN
      drop temporary table if exists temp_table;
      CREATE temporary TABLE temp_table  
      AS (
           SELECT distinct(C.id) FROM table1 AS C
           INNER JOIN table2 AS CA ON CA.college_id in (8192)
           INNER JOIN table3 AS CS ON CS.skill_id in (2744)
         );

      select * from temp_table;

END
```

Comment: Getting another error saying You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''" at line 9. It is the line which is the end of the first query.

Comment: Also, is there a way to run multiple queries without a stored procedure in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @kanishka...its working fine to me on inno_db......check syntax regarding maria db....i haven't worked on maria db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108818/discussion-between-jordan-and-kanishka).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/distinct-optimization.html). There is nothing like `UNIQUE` keyword in MYSQL. try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc`()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE 
  temp_table  
AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT(C.id) FROM table1 AS C
                INNER JOIN table2 AS CA ON CA.college_id in (8192)
                INNER JOIN table3 AS CS ON CS.skill_id in (2744)
);

select * from temp_table;

END
```

Comment: getting another error that says comma or ( is missing near DISTINCT

Comment: @kanishka:- It looks like you are not doing the JOIN properly for your tables. I have edited my answer and tried to JOIN your tables. You can JOIN them using the appropriate columns. try it

Comment: No, the join is proper. The create table query works smoothly if run separately. I wanted to include select also in it. So I put it in a stored procedure. And ended up with the error.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `DISTINCT` instead of `UNIQUE` because UNIQUE is no more in MySQL and second one missing space `table1AS` so modified `table1 AS` and third one you are missing `()` to name of store procedure and last `;` is missing before select query,

So modified query will be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc`()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE 
  temp_table  
AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT(C.id) FROM table1 AS C
                INNER JOIN table2 AS CA ON CA.college_id in (8192)
                INNER JOIN table3 AS CS ON CS.skill_id in (2744)
);

select * from temp_table;

END
```